# Returning a generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, return, assign

I have a class that has two arrays of generic objects:

```
public class Scene {
    objects:[Geometry<BSDF>]
    lights:[Geometry<Emitter>]
...
```

And I have a function which I want to return some element from either one of these arrays:

```
public func hit<M>(origin:Vec, direction:Vec) -> (Geometry<M>?,CGFloat) {
    var minDist = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    var minGeometry:Geometry<M>? = nil
    for g in objects {
        let d = g.intersect(origin: origin, direction: direction)
        if (d != 0 && d < minDist) {
            minDist = d
            minGeometry = g
        }
    }
    // Do the same for lights
    return (minGeometry,minDist)
}
```

However for the line `minGeometry = g` I get the error 'Cannot assign value of type 'Geometry< BSDF >' to type Geometry<_>' am I misunderstanding how generics are working and how I can create such a function?

Comment: The generic type `M` represents a **single** concrete type. So if `M` represents `Emitter` is doesn't match `BSDF`.

Comment: I see, so how can I create a function that returns either a BDSF or Emitter piece of geometry?

Comment: You could use a protocol which both types conform to. The objects must implement `intersect(origin: direction:)`. Then replace `Geometry<M>` with that protocol.